# Cassandra CQL syntax tests

Tags: testing, cassandra, cql, suite

I'm trying to create a thin parser-generator for Cassandra CQL. The goal is to alter statements with custom syntax (i.e. extended CQL) into valid CQL statements. The Cassandra is an open source project, and I expected to find list of all test statements. Could you give a hint on how to find the CQL test statements?

Comment: Asking for software/documentation is explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [build goal](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/build.xml#L222). The generated grammar should help you to validate.